# PHPStan is not interpreting a Symfony EntityRepository as a generic

Tags: php, symfony, generics, phpstan, php-attributes

I'm having trouble making sense of this PHPStan error. PHPStan is saying I need to provide the class string of an EntityRepository of an object. I am providing the class string of a ServiceEntityRepository (which extends EntityRepository) of class "Schedule".

#### Error

> Parameter $repositoryClass of attribute class Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Entity constructor expects
> class-string<Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository<T of object>>|null, 'App\Repository\ScheduleRepository' given.

#### Code

Here is the offending code:

```php
namespace App\Entity\Schedule;

use App\Repository\ScheduleRepository;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: ScheduleRepository::class)]
class Schedule implements JsonSerializable
{
    // ...
```

And the repository class referenced:

```php
namespace App\Repository;

use App\Entity\Schedule\Schedule;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;

/*
 * @extends ServiceEntityRepository<Schedule>
 */
class ScheduleRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    // ...
```

(Note: ServiceEntityRepository extends EntityRepository.)

Comment: Hi @amacrobert, I'm facing the same issue. I didn't find an easy way to fix it. A bug report has been created on phpstan repository: https://github.com/phpstan/phpstan/issues/7171.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a bug in phpstan.

Solution: Upgrade phpstan to 1.6.8.